# camunda exception spindataformatexception

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I am getting SpinDataFormatException in camunda what is this and what can be done to solve this

Error :

```
{"Camunda Exception - {\"type\":\"SpinDataFormatException\",\"message\":\"SPIN-01004 No matching data format detected\"}"}
```

Comment: Which data format (type attribute) are you sending in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the dependencies to Spin Dataformat.
[image]

Check the documentation here: [Camunda Docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/spin/)